# CPanel - Is it possible to download a file with direct link to our own FTP folder?

Tags: ftp, download, automation, cpanel

I was wondering if there is a way to download a file with direct link to my own FTP Folder (using CPanel) without downloading it to my computer first. There are some methods to automate this process but all of which I read about somehow download the file on my computer and then upload it to the FTP folder.

Comment: You'd have to remote in to either the download location or the ftp server and upload/download it directly to the ftp server. If it were possible to remove yourself as a middle man and download files to other computers, that would be a massive security issue.

Comment: yes but i have the credentials for my ftp folder/server.
can you be more specific about your solution?

Comment: You need to log into the ftp server using remote control software, like TeamViewer. Then, while using the ftp server computer, download the file you want.

Comment: What you're looking for doesn't exist. If it did, I would just download a virus onto your computer instead of mine. See the problem here?

Comment: @Wutnaut But without access (login/pass), u can do nothing..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this but not (AFAIK) with cPanel. If you have SSH access to the server then you can issue [an SCP command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427553/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-ssh) (secure copy) that will download the file into the remote server.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something like [this website](http://ctrlq.org/save/) does. I only have my own server's credentials.

Comment: Well.. those guys use the API of the services such as Dropbox, Google drive or OneDrive... The API allows to transfer files to the cloud servers.

Comment: Yes but they don't directly move files to cloud drives, first they download them on their servers and from there to cloud services, plus there is an option in there to download files directly to FTP servers.

Comment: Where's the link to this option? I searched but they didn't give any instructions on how to use it.. so assuming it doesn't exist..

Comment: @Saeed .. and they don't upload to their server then to cloud but they upload directly to cloud using the API of each service.. (see: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#simple)

Comment: What you can't see the FTP option as the file destination in [here](http://ctrlq.org/save/) ?

Comment: Okay I'm not talking about cloud drives here, I'm talking about their FTP option. either they upload a file directly to your FTP server or first they download it on their own servers and then to yours, they get the job done with no API from other cloud services such as Google drive. how about that?

Comment: When you follow the link in; You can even transfer large files from the web to your FTP server directly.. They don't show any FTP solution, just some other providers like WeTransfer etc..